# Geoserver WMS XML Error

Tags: qgis, geoserver, xml

I am trying to load WMS layer from geoserver in QGIS.
The Error in QGIS is :
Failed to Download Capabilities
Download of Capabilities failed: Connection Refused

So I went and found this question:
[Failure to connect QGIS with GeoServer WMS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/231366/failure-to-connect-qgis-with-geoserver-wms)

but the solution in the first answer when I go to the following link:

http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

I get an XML Parsing Error, how can I fix this error?

> XML Parsing Error: not well-formed Location:
>   http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?SERVICE=WMS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities
>   Line Number 6244, Column 50:
>   -34.8977165222168http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">

Ok Update:
Some of the sld styles did not have workspaces assigned to them, once they were sorted I still cannot load th WMS in QGIS.

When I load the localhost get capabilities link same as above ^^^

I no longer get the same error message(progress?)

But now the error states:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Comment: Download the GetCapabilities into disk with the GetCapabilities URL, open the file with text editor and tell what do you see on line 6244.

Comment: line 6244:  <southBoundLatitude>-34.8977165222168</<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ServiceExceptionReport version="1.3.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/wms/1.3.0/exceptions_1_3_0.xsd">   <ServiceException>

Comment: In sublime text the first '<' after the Latitude value is highlighted.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with your server. Can you see your layers with the Layer preview demo of your Geoserver?

Comment: I can preview layers in Geoserver. The instance of geoserver is running in docker if that changes things slightly?

Comment: Hard to say. It seems that there is a connection because first 6243 are downloaded and parsed OK, but then the document is truncated and the  error message follows. Read further the saved response, hopefully the contents of the error message is informative.

Comment: The error further is giving me metadata errors, which were for layers added recently, I am wondering if it is those maybe so am going to work through them and see if I can fix them. error is as follows: Error occurred trying to write out metadata for layer: purchase_plans_digitised
Error occurred trying to write out metadata for layer: purchase_plans_digitised
java.io.IOException: No such resource: purchase_plans_digitised.sld
No such resource: purchase_plans_digitised.sld

Answer (score 2):

One (or more) of your layers is broken. Goto the global settings menu and change the Service Error Settings from `return service exception` to `skipping misconfigured layers`.

[image]

This will now work in QGis but one (or more) layers will be missing. You need to look at why those layers are not working.

Comment: So it looks like somehow some of my styles 'lost' their workspaces and these were the error layers, am hoping this may fix it. thanks

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same error too so I change my Z value and M value layers from enabled to disabled, and it works!